# Check dates in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im looking to figure out a way to have todays date in Cell A1, and then in Cell B2 a formula to use the date in A1 add 3 days to it and then populate in Cell B2, i dont want the date in Cell B2 to change when i open the sheet up each day though as this date is being used as a check date and will have conditional formatting to it. Is this a possibility with a formula?

Im a novice with formulas and so ive not tried anything as im unsure on where to start

Comment: There is a function to get date - =TODAY() to get todays date. =TODAY()+3 would give the result you want, but it will recalculate every time you open your workbook. So you either need to add "todays" date manually or use VBA to do it

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me, do you know of anyway to stop the dates in B1 from automatically updating without having to manually enter the date in A1?

Comment: For example you could add button with VBA which pressed would write current date into A1 cell

Comment: Thats not a bad idea, not sure why i didnt think of that thanks for your help on this one mate

Comment: Does this [static date](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-b5663451-10b0-40ab-9e71-6b0ce5768138) method works ?